# why persistence context is not cleared?

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions, entity, entitymanager

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
void test(MemberEntity namedEntity) {
    repository.save(entity);
    
    entityManager.clear();
    
    List<MemberEntity> result = repository
            .search(PageRequest.of(0, 100), searchCause, memberEntity.modifiedDate.desc())
            .getContent();
}
```

I thought that when repository save proceeds, it is saved in the persistence context, and clear will remove the entity from the persistence context.

And I thought that an empty value would come out when the repository.search proceeds because the entity is removed from the persistence context before it is flushed, but the saved namedEntity is output, so I have doubts.

English is insufficient, but thank you for reading and ask for a reply.

Comment: you should invoke entityManager.flush();

Comment: @tremendous7 I tried it and it doesn't work and the same symptoms occur.

Comment: the `save` will be executed directly, so the new record is visible for the current transaction. Clear will only clear the 1st level cache. However the search will still find it because it it in the database (according to the transaction).

Comment: @M.Deinum
If you look at the implementation of CrudRepository save, you know that em.persist is called and persist is reflected in the db at the moment of flush. Is there any reason why it is flushed before the transaction ends?

Comment: persist is immediate because it needs to get the id for the entity. So it is directly part of the transaction. Flush isn't the same as a commit!.